# Inserir em 2 tabelas Entity framwork - 1 to 1

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

Tenho duas entidades geradas pelo wizard do code-first:

**Pessoa**

```
 [Table("pessoa")]
    public partial class pessoa
    {
        public pessoa()
        {
            pessoa_endereco = new HashSet<pessoa_endereco>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        [Required]
        [StringLength(1)]
        public string tipo { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string razao_social { get; set; }

        [StringLength(100)]
        public string nome_fantasia { get; set; }

        [StringLength(14)]
        public string cpf_cnpj { get; set; }

        [StringLength(15)]
        public string rg_insc_estadual { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual administrador administrador { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual banco banco { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual cliente cliente { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual filial filial { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual fornecedor fornecedor { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<pessoa_endereco> pessoa_endereco { get; set; }

        public virtual usuario usuario { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual vendedor vendedor { get; set; }
    }
```

**Usuário - Relacionamento 1 to 1 com pessoa (pessoa.id = usuario.id)**

```
   [Table("usuario")]
    public partial class usuario
    {
        public usuario()
        {
            caixa = new HashSet<caixa>();
            pedido_venda = new HashSet<pedido_venda>();
            usuario_perfil = new HashSet<usuario_perfil>();
            usuario_permissao = new HashSet<usuario_permissao>();
        }

        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string login { get; set; }

        [StringLength(50)]
        public string senha { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "char")]
        [StringLength(1)]
        public string ativo { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<caixa> caixa { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<pedido_venda> pedido_venda { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual pessoa pessoa { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<usuario_perfil> usuario_perfil { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual ICollection<usuario_permissao> usuario_permissao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Tenho 2 controllers criados dinamicamente pelo ajudante, com o Entity Framework. Como faço para criar um Controller que Insira os dados de uma só vez nas 2 entidades?

Controller pessoa

```
namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    public class pessoasController : ApiController
    {
        private ModelTake db = new ModelTake();

        // GET: api/pessoas
        public IQueryable<pessoa> Getpessoa()
        {
            return db.pessoa;
        }

        // GET: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Getpessoa(int id)
        {
            pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Find(id);
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(pessoa);
        }

        // PUT: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult Putpessoa(int id, pessoa pessoa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != pessoa.id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(pessoa).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!pessoaExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/pessoas
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Postpessoa(pessoa pessoa)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateException)
            {
                if (pessoaExists(pessoa.id))
                {
                    return Conflict();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = pessoa.id }, pessoa);
        }

        // DELETE: api/pessoas/5
        [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
        public IHttpActionResult Deletepessoa(int id)
        {
            pessoa pessoa = db.pessoa.Find(id);
            if (pessoa == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.pessoa.Remove(pessoa);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(pessoa);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool pessoaExists(int id)
        {
            return db.pessoa.Count(e => e.id == id) > 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Código acrescentado ao sistema (Resposta de Cassio) para quem estiver interessado.

Controller:

```
 var usuario = new usuario
            {
                id = pessoa.id,
                login = pessoa.usuario.login,
                senha = pessoa.usuario.senha,
                ativo = pessoa.usuario.ativo
            };

            db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);
            usuario.pessoa = pessoa;
            db.usuario.Add(usuario);
```

Json de exemplo usado pra inserir!

```
{
   "id": 4,
   "tipo": "J",
   "razao_social": "INTELIDER",
   "nome_fantasia": "INTELIDER",
   "cpf_cnpj": "0",
   "rg_insc_estadual": "0",
   "usuario":    {
      "id": 4,
      "login": "gleyson",
      "senha": "123456",
      "ativo": "S"
   }
}
```

Comment: Mas se você preencher o objeto do tipo *pessoa* e a propriedade *usuario*, quando aplica as alterações o `Entity Framework` já deveria inserir nas duas tabelas.

Comment: Acrescentei o controller de pessoa a pergunta, como posso implementar nele isso é meu problema:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neste caso basta você preencher o objeto usuário, e definir a propriedade pessoa do objeto usuário com o objeto pessoa do parâmetro, e depois basta salvar.

```
// POST: api/pessoas
    [ResponseType(typeof(pessoa))]
    public IHttpActionResult Postpessoa(pessoa pessoa)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        var usuario = new usuario{
            Login = "Preencha",
            Senha = "Preencha",
            ...
        };

        db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);
        usuario.pessoa = pessoa;
        db.usuario.Add(usuario);

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateException)
        {
            if (pessoaExists(pessoa.id))
            {
                return Conflict();
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = pessoa.id }, pessoa);
    }
```

Comment: ok Cassio, vou almoçar assim que voltar já vou testar e se funcionar já marco como resposta

Comment: como você disse:   `var usuario = new usuario
            {
                id = pessoa.id,
                login = "gleyson",
                senha = "123456",
                ativo = "S"
            };

            db.pessoa.Add(pessoa);
            usuario.pessoa = pessoa;
            db.usuario.Add(usuario);`, porém coloquei os valores manualmente, como faria para passar os valores do usuario para esse controller em json por exemplo, já que na classe pessoa não aparecem os campos de usuario?, só falta isso pra fechar, não sei se to sendo claro nessa explicação.

Comment: por exemplo usei o json no soapui : `{
   "id": 2,
   "tipo": "J",
   "razao_social": "INTELIDER",
   "nome_fantasia": "INTELIDER",
   "cpf_cnpj": "0",
   "rg_insc_estadual": "0"
}`, como faria para inserir também, através dele, os dados do usuário?

Comment: Sim, te disse para colocar manualmente apenas como teste. Em relação há, de onde vai vir os dados para criar o objeto usuario, irá depender da sua logica, não sei qual logica pretende usar, e de onde estes dados irão vir.

Comment: consegui, obrigado pela sua ajuda, coloquei acima o exemplo de como implementei para alguém que tiver a mesma dúvida!

Comment: Que bom que deu certo.